# wpf - how to use dataTemplate for treeViewItems

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

The following code throws an exception:

```
<TreeView 
            ItemsSource="{Binding TreeRootInstance}"
            x:Name="Htree"
            ItemTemplate="CellTemplate"
            SelectedItemChanged="HTree_OnSelectedItemChanged"
            KeyDown="HTree_KeyDown">

            <TreeView.Resources>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate">
                    <Border>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                      Focusable="False"
                                      Grid.Column="1"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vw:TreeViewItem}}}"
                                      ClickMode="Press"/>
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                Grid.Column="0"  />


                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>



                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" x:Key="aa">
                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Property="TabIndex" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Children}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Border Name="Bd">

                                </Border>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                                    <Setter TargetName="ItemsHost"
                                            Property="Visibility"
                                            Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </Trigger>

                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>


            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource aa}" />
            </Style>

            </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

(I've omitted some of the code but the main hirerchy is still there...)
The exception is a xaml parse exception, on ItemsControl.ItemTemplate.

Could you please tell me how to make this code work?

Thanks,
Li

Comment: What is the inner exception of the XamlParseException?

Comment: Just "ItemsControl.ItemTemplate" threw an exception".

Comment: Why is the vw: prefix there?  Is this a non-standard TreeView?

Comment: Shouldn't be there... I'll edit this immediately. The error persists even with a standard TreeView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a plain string as a resource locator, you need to use either a StaticResource markup extension, i.e., `ItemTempate="{StaticResource CellTemplate}"`

Comment: THanks, But now I'm getting another type of exception (on the same line) - again, a xaml parse error, this time "Provide value on "System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension" threw an exception"

Comment: Move your TreeView.Resources just below your openeing TreeView tag; all resources need to be declared before they are referenced.

Answer (score 2):

The ItemTemplate line should read:

```
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CellTemplate}"
```